# Fetch document in a given date range in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a database in MongoDB called `goalsdata`. There is a collection `new_goals`. The document looks like,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2d0f71ee19fb0021e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "goals",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-21T15:02:09.784Z")


},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2d0f71ee19fb0031e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "goals",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-22T15:03:09.784Z")

},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2d0f71ee19fb0041e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "goals",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-23T15:02:08.784Z")

},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6b2d0f71ee19fb001e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "goals",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-24T15:02:07.784Z")

},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("8b2d0f71ee19fb001e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "countries_goals_exams",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-26T15:02:06.784Z")

}
```

There is a key called `request_time`. I want to make a query and fetch the document where `request_time` range is between `2018-06-19` to `2018-06-21` .

As, `2018-06-19` `request_time` is not there. So, it will consider the given range and show me the output,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b2d0f71ee19fb0021e0000f0"),
    "method" : "GET",
    "action" : "goals",
    "request_time" : ISODate("2018-06-21T15:02:09.784Z")


}
```

I can fetch the data from last one hour ago in MongoDB by using this query,

```
db.getCollection('new_goals').entity.find({ $and:[
    {
    "timestamp": {
        $gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60)
    }}, 
    { 
    "timestamp": {
        $lte: ISODate()
    }}
]})
```

But, I want to use key `request_time` and the range to fetch the data. What is the recommended way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adjust your time range accordingly:

```
db.new_goals.find({
    request_time: {
        $gte: new Date('2018-06-19'), 
        $lt: new Date('2018-06-22')
    }
})
```